# Scanning multiple channels using polling on STM32f401Re

Tags: stm32, hal-library

I am using ADC to measure different voltages and I need a total of 15 channels and I need to measure ADC in a polling mechanism. When I use

```
HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
```

It gives me value for only one ADC channel I am unable to receive values for other ADC channels. Can you all please help me how to scan multiple ADC channels using polling.

My ADC configuration is as follows.

```
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{
 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */
 
  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */
 
  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */
 
  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */
  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 15;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  sConfig.Rank = 2;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_3;
  sConfig.Rank = 3;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_4;
  sConfig.Rank = 4;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_5;
  sConfig.Rank = 5;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_6;
  sConfig.Rank = 6;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_7;
  sConfig.Rank = 7;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_8;
  sConfig.Rank = 8;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_9;
  sConfig.Rank = 9;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_10;
  sConfig.Rank = 10;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_11;
  sConfig.Rank = 11;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_12;
  sConfig.Rank = 12;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_13;
  sConfig.Rank = 13;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_14;
  sConfig.Rank = 14;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_15;
  sConfig.Rank = 15;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */
 
  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */
 
}
```

My main code is as follows

```
while (1)
  {
 
      while(interrupt_state == TRUE)
      {
                   HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
          for(int i = 0; i< Max_Channels; i++)
          {
              //HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
              HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
              adcValue[i] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
             
              counter++;
          }
 
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
 
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      }
      if(interrupt_state == FALSE)
      {
          HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
          printf("Counter value is: %d\r\n",counter);
          interrupt_state = TRUE;
          counter = 0;
      }
 
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to scan different channels of the ADC by going through this [example](https://controllerstech.com/stm32-adc-multi-channel-without-dma/) also I made certain changes in the code that allowed me to scan a particular channel of ADC. The details are well versed also whenever you can `HAL_ADC_START(&handle_for_adc);` it starts scanning from the beginning as multiple channels are been declared in the `MX_ADC1_Init()`. So my code is as follows.

We won't initialize any channels in the ADC init where as we will initialize them in another function

```
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */
  /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

The main function will be as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  MX_TIM4_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
//  uint32_t test_data = 0;
  HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
  while (1)
  {

          for(int i = 0; i< Max_Channels; i++)
          {
              select_adc_channel(i+1);
              HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
              HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
              adcValue[i] = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
//            HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);

          }
          HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Now we will need to select or initialize the channel first or before starting the ADC so I am using a `void select_adc_channel(int channel)` function in which we can pass the channel which we want to select.

The function is as follows:

```
void select_adc_channel(int channel)
{
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;
    switch (channel)
    {
        case 1:
            sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;

              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;

        case 2:
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
        case 3:
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_3;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
        case 4:
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_4;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
        case 5:
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_5;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
        case 6:
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_6;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
        case 7:
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_7;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
        case 8:
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_8;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
        case 9:
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_9;
              sConfig.Rank = 9;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
        case 10:
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_10;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
        case 11:
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_11;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
        case 12:
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_12;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
        case 13:
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_13;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
        case 14:
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_14;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;
              /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
              */
        case 15:
              sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_15;
              sConfig.Rank = 1;
              if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
              {
                Error_Handler();
              }
              break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

As my sample time is constant I have written `sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;` this only once if you want to change the cycle then you can pass another parameter for changing the cycles and use them in the switch case.

Comment: Why do you set `rank` and call `HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel` in every `case`:)) You just set the channel in cases and set rank and call that function after `switch` is finished, only once:))

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct but slightly redundant: one could use macro expansions skip all the `case`s as such:

```
#define ADC_CHNL(x) ADC_CHANNEL_##x
```

And then change the  channel selection line into

```
sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHNL(channel);
```